# How to make a link for one page of asp.net core local project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

https://localhost:7099/RFS/ConfirmDetails?TranCompNo= , that is already a link but i have to change localhost and 7099 to make the link accessible in any computer. What should i do to make it accessible in any computer?

https://localhost:7099/RFS/ConfirmDetails?TranCompNo= , this will still show after clicking the link or maybe you guys have better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your ASPNetCore project accessible on other computers, you need to publish it to a hosting service.

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for a general overview of publishing ASPNetCore projects. That page also contains a link to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0), which describes how you can publish your app to Azure.

Azure is probably one of the simplest ways to host your application, because Microsoft has integrated a lot of their tooling with it (you can publish directly from Visual Studio), but there are many other options for ASPNetCore hosting - have a google if you need other options.